# Email Report Generator for Github

Tags: email, reporting, github

For those that are in software development teams, and use github or other VCS' to track issues. Do you have a daily generated report email that shows the current state on each repo (total # of open issues, closed issues, in dev, etc.) and who is assigned to them and their status?
I'm part of a large software dev team and we have a custom built solution that does this but we are kind of scaling out of it and was wondering are there current solutions out there that do this? Ie. an app that's onprem and plugs into your github enterprise and creates scheduled emails about specific repo's you set.

Would love to know what other teams do to get more visibility about current issue status in a quick manner.

Answer (score 1):

We use some python scripts running on our Jenkins machine to generate summaries of both the build statuses and the ticketing via the APIs and post the results with links to the projects & trackers.  For some projects we also generate XLSX using xlwt python library for customer summaries of the tracker progress.

Works really well.